# Can I automate Assign function when creating a Merge Request in GitLab?

Tags: merge, gitlab, assign

I am curious if it's possible to have the Assign function automatically set a pre-defined list of assignees when creating a Merge Request in GitLab.
I thought I might automate this function so I don't have to add assignees myself every time I make a Merge Reuqest.
Codeowners function provided by GitLab seems to not work in this regard... Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign approval settings to merge requests by navigating to your project Settings > General > Merge Requests. You can create specific rules for a certain branch or for all branches:
[image: merge request approvals]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found this functionality and I guess it's my best bet. Do you know if I in the Approvers section appeared a person and in the place where there is master branch in your picture is a star (*) and there is a Code Owners label above that person - that means that GitLab read my CODEOWNERS file successfully and that person has access to approving all the branches of the project?

Comment: FYI: Approval rules are only included in the premium version (docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/…)

Comment: An approver is NOT a reviewer, nor a MR assignee